# Max length not applied in migration

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am using efcore.sqlserver 1.0.1 with preview2 tools - I have a string property which in sql server is created as an nvchar(max) field. When I add a data annotation stringlength(100) to the property and add a new migration the migration does not alter the column at all.

However if I add a Required and StringLength annotation then the generated migration alters the column and shows ( .. maxLength: 100, nullable: false )

Why does it only do this if I change the nullable value?

Comment: How are you generating your migration?

Comment: dotnet ef Migrations add ...

Comment: Using `[MaxLength]` with or without `[Required]` should enforce the maximum length for a string property. What provider are you using? Also, can you give a code example for the model?

Comment: I get the same issue using EF 6.1.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you need to use `MaxLengthAttribute` instead of `StringLengthAttribute`.

https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/max-length.html#data-annotations

This is probably because the `StringLength` attribute has an option for minimum length, which is not supported natively by SQL, and therefore the `MaxLength` attribute is a better fit for this use case.

Just to be clear, attributes have no effect in and of themselves. They can contain logic and information, but must be utilized via reflection from another piece of code during the normal execution model. This is with the exception of certain attributes which are given special meaning by the compiler, such as the `Conditional` attribute.

**EDIT**

The author found that this is a known issue for cases when the tool set has been upgraded from RC2 => RTM.

https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/195

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately there is no such issue on the EF core :) I have tested your scenario and it is working fine.

You have to use  `[MaxLength(100)]` attribute for that.Here is the doc : [**MaxLength Data Annotations**](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/max-length.html#data-annotations)

**Test case :** I used MaxLength as 500 for my test.

Firstly I have created a property like this :

```
 public string Title { get; set; }
```

**After migration :**

[image]

After that I have changed it like this :

```
 [MaxLength(500)]
 public string Title { get; set; }
```

**After migration :**

[image]

**Generated Script :**

```
  migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
                name: "Title",
                table: "Posts",
                maxLength: 500,
                nullable: true);
```

**Tested Tools version :**

```
 <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools"
 version="1.0.0-preview2-final" targetFramework="net461"
 developmentDependency="true" />
```

Comment: The question is about `StringLengthAttribute`.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris there is no such thing on the EF core.please see this https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/max-length.html#data-annotations

Comment: I tried maxLength too and it doesn't generate anything in Migration. I guess it has something to do with my setup.

Comment: @Sampath Right. Which is why your answer doesn't apply.

Comment: Now I'm confused. Maybe this is an issue with a particular tools version.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris attributes themselves don't do anything. You can apply an attribute from a namespace not known to EF Core, and it will happily ignore it.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris This is the tool version which I have tested : `<package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" version="1.0.0-preview2-final" targetFramework="net461" developmentDependency="true" />`

Comment: Ok - i just realised this is the problem https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/195

In my initial migrations the length is hidden in code behind and set to 100, so migration builder thinks nothing has changed - but the db field has nvarchar(max) on it, cause latest version doesn't use that code behind.

Comment: Please answer the question, then. Good find!

Comment: @Christopher my point is that in order to let an attribute actually affect something, it must be known to Entity Framework. I can't find a list of supported attributes, but if for example `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute` isn't supported, then applying that attribute will have no effect, and you'll need to find one that _is_ supported, such as `MaxLengthAttribute`.

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't understand where you got the impression that I don't know how attributes work, but what you're saying is pretty much what I summarized in my original answer. I have updated the answer to state this explicitly, so as to not mislead other readers.

Comment: @Christopher I'm talking about your first comment on this answer. Sure, the question may be about `StringLenghtAttribute`, but this answer explains you should use `MaxLengthAttribute`.

Comment: @CodeCaster The original post did not contain that and was only added after my comment. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Chris I now see, should've noticed. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @CodeCaster I too should have noticed the change and responded thusly. Thanks for taking time to sort this out. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using **HasMaxLength** and **MaxLengthAttribute**/**StringLength**  together, becouse data base Configure() **HasMaxLength** have priority over **MaxLengthAttribute**. Watch code example down below

*Column Model*

```
[MaxLength(500)]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

*Configuring*

```
  public class TableNameConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TableName>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TableName> builder)
        {
           //.HasMaxLength takes precedence over operation MaxLengthAttribute(500)
           builder.Property(x => x.Title ).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(20);
        }
    }
```

With this parameters **Migration** will generate maxLength = 20 for Title

```
 migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "TableName",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Title= table.Column<string>(maxLength: 20, nullable: true)
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I face this problem when I use EF Core code first. I change my migration code `entity.Property(t => t.UserName).HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(256)` to
`entity.Property(t => t.UserName).HasColumnType("varchar(256)")`
and now it's working fine.